# How does R handle conflict for a method present in multiple packages?

Tags: r

Suppose there is a method (let's say "sample ()") and that it is present in multiple packages (let's say both in package "base" and "arules"). Now if I call sample () which package is called, does it call the package "base" or "arules" and how does it decide which one to call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It selects which one comes first on the `search` path:

```
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:arules"    "package:Matrix"   
 [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
 [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

So it would be the arules version. This is an S4 method which actually may call the base version anyway. Note that base is always last on the search path, and the global environment is always first. Generally packages are loaded in second place (can be changed with the `pos` argument to `library`), and moved down as others are loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
base::sample()
arules::sample()
```

Comment: The load package sequence define the function in use, I guess.